# Download zing chart as pdf using itextsharp

Tags: itext, zingchart

I am using zing chart to display various charts on client side. Now there is a requirement to download all the charts in one pdf. For pdf generation I am using itextsharp. Is there any way by which I can integrate zing charts so that itextsharp can render and create pdf containing all charts?

Answer (score 1):

No, there isnt'.

I think the best way to solve your usecase would be:
1. to send a call to the server (containing information about what charts the user wants to have)
2. at the server side, handle incoming requests by producing the graph (as an image), adding all images in a pdf, pushing the bytes of the pdf back into an HTTP message

For generating charts at the server side, have a look at http://nugetmusthaves.com/Tag/Chart

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes I thought of similar alternative, but I am not able to product graph (as an image) at server side..Can you elaborate or share some link. Thanks

Comment: I added a link to an overview of chart-libraries for .net
Kindly upvote my answer if you find it satisfactory.

Comment: Thanks will have a look at it :)